# O .NET Core já está estável o suficiente para produção?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

O .NET Core já está estável e confiável a ponto de ser usado em ambientes de produção para sites comerciais?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[O .NET Core passa ser a única opção em 2020 e se chamará .NET 5](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/385594/101). Então a pergunta já não faz muito sentido e está aqui por questões históricas.

---

Sim, dá para dizer que sim. Mas com algum cuidado.

Primeiro precisaríamos definir o que é ser "estável para produção".

Quando a Microsoft lançou a versão 1.0 dele o classificou **estável para produção**. Então objetiva e oficialmente podemos dizer que sim, está pronto para ser usado em aplicações comerciais.

De fato muita gente já está usando nessas condições.

Algumas pessoas reclamam de algumas coisas. Inclusive da falta de alguns componentes. Alguns que nunca serão implementados porque não faz sentido no .NET Core (mas até isso mudou um pouco), outros que precisamos esperar um pouco, ou obter alguma alternativa, como muitas pessoas fizeram.

Por exemplo, o Entity Framework Core será bem melhor quando estiver completo, mas agora faltam várias coisas. Algumas não terão porque nunca foi adequado nas versões anteriores, como o *model first*.

Ele funciona de forma diferente do .NET Framework, então pra quem está acostumado, pode ser um pouco difícil se adaptar. Algumas coisas podem não funcionar porque a pessoa não sabe o jeito novo. Outras coisas podem não estar funcionando bem mesmo. Mas nada crítico que não dê para usar. Claro, pode dar um pouco mais de trabalho ser pioneiro (*early adopter*). Mas não há *bugs* absurdos comprometedores. (Bem, isso já está meio ultrapassado, valia mais quando escrevi originalmente).

Talvez falte um pouco de ferramenta. Já existem muitas bibliotecas famosas portadas para ele, mas não tudo. Mas falta cada vez menos.

Já temos atualizações que melhoraram algumas coisas. Quando [o 2.0 saiu](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/roadmap.md), já bem mais estável ainda e bem mais completo ficou mais próximo da nível que todos desejam. O Visual Studio 2017 já vem com suporte bem melhorado a ele, e haverá atualizações ao longo do tempo. O novo já está caminho para até passar o suporte que o o *framework* tradicional tem.

Se vai portar algo antigo para o .NET Core, não sei se é a melhor ideia nesse momento. E dependendo do que usar, nem se será interessante em algum momento. Alguma coisa precisa de tanta adaptação que só compensa se fizer do zero, o que muitos dirão que é loucura (na verdade depende da qualidade do antigo, do tamanho, e outras questões menos técnicas).

No fundo só você pode responder se está bom para o que precisa. Tem que começar usar e ver. Tem gente com experiência que tentou usar, encontrou algum obstáculo e desistiu por hora, tem quem conseguiu se virar bem, mesmo sem entender muito daquilo. Então a experiência de cada um é única, e depende do empenho posto e necessidade que a pessoa tem.

Muitas pessoas acham o PHP 7 estável. Pra mim não rola, eu teria mais dificuldade de portar minhas aplicações PHP para o 7 do que fazer uma nova aplicação para o .NET Core. Mas não posso dizer que as pessoas que acham ele estável são malucos, ignorantes, ou algo do tipo, depende de cada um.

<strike>Recentemente</strike> estive no Microsoft MVP Communuty Connection e tinha muito MVP já usando em produção com sucesso.

Quando [saiu o 2.1](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-net-core-2-1/?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) praticamente se completou o que se esperava do 2.0 e já é bem completo no seu núcleo (sem trocadilho) e o que faltou vem no [próximo 2.2](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/307). Claro que o ASP.NET ainda falta um pouco mais, mas pouco, o EF está um pouco atrasado e tem uma intenção diferente, mas ele já tem muita coisa nova interessante que o EF clássico não tem.

Em 2019 [surge o 3.0](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/net-core-3-and-support-for-windows-desktop-applications/?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) que acho que completa o ciclo e até mesmo atende quase todas necessidades que o .NET Framework atendia, inclusive as específicas do Windows através do kits de compatibilidade (não fará parte da distribuição básica, mas é super fácil inserir na aplicação). O que não entrar é porque não é para usar mesmo. E olhe que até o Windows Forms será suportado. Inclusive pode usar o EF 6 para quem precisa de algo exclusivo dele que não pode abrir mão.

Minha visão, sem nenhuma informação privilegiada por ser Microsoft MVP, é que o .NET Framework se tornará secundário e receberá menos atualização por decisão política, mas também técnica, que acho que não vem ao caso neste pergunta. Não só todo investimento será no Core, mas a comunidade está colaborando muito nele, não tem como fazer isto no Framework por razões que também não vem ao caso aqui.

Então tentei responder objetivamente e não tentar cair em opiniões, porque cada um tem a sua.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Muito esclarecedora sua resposta. Quanto a ser uma pergunta "datada", eu posso adicionar a versão na qual me refiro no título da pergunta, assim fica mais preciso.

Comment: @RenanCavalieri a questão não é essa, é que essa resposta vale hoje, amanha ela não vale mais, se a pessoa não se compromete em atualizar ela fica quase errada. Ano que vem alguém vem aqui ler e pensa, "ouw ainda tem gente que tem algum problema", mas ano que vem isso pode não ser verdade mais. Daqui 2 anos a importância da pergunta fica reduzida, porque todo mundo saberá que ele é estável.

Comment: Bom, opinião de um desenvolvedor Java do outro lado da cerca aqui: Tive uma experiência recente usando NET Core 1.X  para SSO com uma série de integrações com Active Directory Federation Services, Kerberos e soluções *third-party*com OpenID Connect e SAML. Enquanto alguns desenvolvedores mais experientes reclamaram bastante da falta de alguns recursos do *WIF* e *WS-Fed* (muito código de *plumbing* teve que ser escrito) a solução saiu e está bem estável, rodando no Linux com pouquíssimos incidentes. Para um ambiente razoavelmente novo e "incompleto" fiquei bastante satisfeito com o resultado.

Comment: @Maniero tenho um sistema em ASP.NET Framework e estou desenvolvendo um outro em ASP.NET Core, o que você quis dizer com "O .NET Core passa ser a única opção em 2020" ? .NET Framework será descontinuado/perderá suporte?

Comment: Não perderá suporte, mas não terá mais evolução. https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/385594/101